# Uncaught error when adding revolution slider to octobercms

Tags: jquery, octobercms

This error occurs when i try to use revolution slider in October though its perfectly working in an html project. I am also using static pages plugin so i had to add this to a snippet. I need the slider to fill the page.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'from' on string '['revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js:7 
    at Function.updateMarkup (revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js:7)
    at HTMLHeadingElement.<anonymous> (revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js:7)
    at Function.each (3f808a46c2a1a9daef9d680daa9c8fb8-1568121211:2)
    at Function.animateTheCaptions (revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js:7)
    at swapSlideProgress (jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7)
    at Object.target (jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7)
    at Object.h._callback (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
    at Object.h.render (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
    at Object.h.render (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
    at Object.D._updateRoot.G.render (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:60)
```

Comment: Seeing as this is a paid item I won't trouble shoot for you. But I would suspect make sure that the initializing code is after loading jquery. You should bring this attention to the revolution slider creator.

Comment: @PettisBrandon yes the initializing code is after the loading query. It just seems not to be the best solution to use this slider with octobercms

Comment: Have you tried to add this to a CMS Page? Instead of through the Static Page Snippet?

Comment: @PettisBrandon yes i was trying to edit through the cms page